# A strange decimal number on top of my plot of a pandas series

Tags: time-series, pandas

I am using the EU stock market dataset, and applied a box-cox transformation to each time series using `stats.boxcox` from the scipy module.

The resulting data frame is `df_box_cox`.

```
df_box_cox.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1860 entries, 0 to 1859
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   DAX     1860 non-null   float64
 1   SMI     1860 non-null   float64
 2   CAC     1860 non-null   float64
 3   FTSE    1860 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 58.2 KB
```

When I run `df_box_cox["DAX"].plot()`, I get:

[image]

Why do I get that pesky number on the top left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a programming question than a data science question and would therefore be better suited to the stackoverflow stackexchange. The numbers you are seeing are related to ticklabel formats used by the `matplotlib` library. Changing the axis settings should allow you to get rid of the numbers on the top left of the plot:

```
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
# or
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
```

For more in-depth information on the offset and style see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28373421/9435355) or the [`matplotlib` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure where to post the question...

Answer (score 0):

Adapting to my setting,

```
axes = df_box_cox["DAX"].plot()

axes.ticklabel_format(axis='y', useOffset=False,style='plain')
```